# OpenOffice Calc doesn't show up in the alt-tab window switcher

Tags: libreoffice, application-switcher

I just upgraded to ubuntu 12.04, and it's *mostly* working.  My biggest problem so far: OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc doesn't show up under the task switcher.

When I pres alt-tab to change windows, I can see all my windows *except* for any OpenOffice documents I have open.  If I minimize other windows, then I can get to my Calc documents, but Alt-Tab just doesn't work.

It only seems to be a problem with Calc.  Writer and Impress both work fine.

I do a lot of work in spreadsheets, so this is really messing up my flow.  Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/942222.
On my machine, however I can't reproduce it, and libreoffice appears in alt-tab switching...

Comment: It doesn't always happen for me either.  Some sessions Calc shows up, other times it doesn't.  Rebooting (usually) seems to fix it.  No idea why.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with LibreOffice Writer.  To solve it I just restart Unity by opening a terminal window and entering: `unity --replace & disown`.  Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the calc window back, then you can try hitting restart and then it will prompt you to save/discard the sheet so they will appear again at which point you can hit "cancel".

I hope they can fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of such issues in 12.04.  This happened to me for GIMP.  That bug has since been fixed.

My advice is to ensure that you are up to date with all packages - don't just install 12.04, but install all `-updates` as there have been literally hundreds of post-release updates to Unity and related packages to fix bugs like this.

It is possible, however, that some such bugs remain.